# Javascript: difference with using return to call a callback?

Tags: javascript, callback, return

Imagine code like this:

```
function foo(data) {
    // ... do something with data
}

function do(userInput, callback) {
    callback(userInput);
}

function doWithReturn(userInput, callback) {
    return callback(userInput);
}

// ...
do('Hello, World', foo);
doWithReturn('Hello, World', foo);
```

Is there any benefit to ever using plain do() and not doWithReturn()?

I ask because, hypothetically, if we didn't know what foo() did internally (i.e. maybe it has a return statement, maybe it just fires a dumb `alert(data)`), using doWithReturn to invoke foo() always just seems "safer" since if foo() happens to return a value, NOT using doWithReturn is clearly wrong.

Comment: Entirely depends on the nature of the functions you're writing. When your `do/doWithReturn` functions become more of a real-world application, it usually becomes clearer if the return value should be passed on.

Comment: Using a function without knowing how it works internally is ok, but I wouldn't use a function without knowing what it returns...

Answer (score 0):

If a function returns a value, this suggests that it can be useful. I would pick a name for the function, and once a scenario emerges where some return value would be beneficial, I'd add a return value.

I don't know if this answers your question.